# Website Search Results Not Showing Images

Tags: search

anyone here knows why my search results are not showing images?
here is my code: https://pastebin.com/sgCTnDcd

Comment: Please move the code into the question. A question here should never rely on an external source.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
if($row->type=='post'){
    $result = wp_get_attachment_image_src ($attachment_id, 'medium');
    $url_img = $result['url'];

    $permalink = get_permalink($row->id);
}
```

You are using `attachment_id` variable, but you have not initiated it anywhere.

```
if($row->type=='post'){
    $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($row->id);
    $result = wp_get_attachment_image_src ($attachment_id, 'medium');
    $url_img = $result['url'];

    $permalink = get_permalink($row->id);
}
```

Comment: still the same. No image. I changed it to  $result = wp_get_attachment_image_src (get_post_thumbnail_id($row->ID), 'medium');
                  $url_img = $result['url'];

Comment: @Dale Can you add `echo 'post_id= ' . $row->ID . ', att_id= ' . (int)$attachment_id . '<br>';`  before `$result = wp_get_attachment_image_src...` to see if you have attachments?

Comment: im getting post_id= , att_id= 0 error

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: do you know other solutions? thanks

Comment: My mistake, should be `$row->id`, not `$row->ID`.

Comment: I changed it to $row->id and result is still the same.

Comment: @Dale Does the query return any results?

Comment: yes it shows the text but no image.

Comment: @Dale Check if `get_post_thumbnail_id($row->id)` and `wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'medium')` return results.

Comment: i'm not getting results if im changing it to wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id, 'medium') im getting big image

Comment: @Dale Try `wp_get_attachment_metadata` [(doc here)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) to check image sizes.

Comment: am i going to replace the wp_get_attachment_image_src to wp_get_attachment_metadata?